# SFML image loading fails on release version - filename corruption

Tags: c++, image, textures, sfml

using VC++, while in Debug mode, everything works OK. But when I create a Release, it won't load images, supposedly because of corruption of the filename.

The code looks like this:

```
Pozadi.loadFromFile("gfx/splash.png");
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Failed to load image "splash.png \♫" Reason: Unable to open file
```

And other images give me even weirder filenames, like a completely corrupt path name.

Any idea what might be the cause?

Thanks

Comment: Pleaso show us the implementation of `loadFromFile()`

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your response, but loadFromFile() is a method of sf::Texture class defined by the SFML libraries.

Comment: Yes, but we cant help you without knowing what this method does exactly (line for line), otherwise why dont you try to attach a debugger?

Comment: Good thing SFML is open source. I've found in its source these three functions, that are used one inside another to load an image from file: http://pastebin.com/ZaupPajP

Comment: I can't imagine what is causing name corruption, since, according to that source code, it is just forwarding the string by const reference straight through. But often these opening failures on different configurations have to do with the working directory from the program's point of view. Try to open that same file using `std::ifstream`, does it succeed? Or rather, does it succeed and fail under the same conditions as the call to `loadFromFile`?

Comment: I've tried the ifstream, both Debug and Release can find the file (the stream object can be printed as a string of random looking characters ending with PNG, so I know it could find the file). I have also thought that the images weren't loading because of the working directory, so I had it printed and it matches with the location of the .exe and the /gfx folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd behavior of strings is a common issue when mixing debug and release versions of libraries or essentially just the runtime library.

If you're in debug mode, you'll have to link against the SFML libraries with the `-d` suffix (e.g. `sfml-graphics-d`). If you're in release mode, you'll have to link against the SFML libraries without the `-d` suffix (e.g. `sfml-graphics`). If you're linking statically make sure you choose either the static or dynamic runtime library depending on how the SFML libraries are built.

If that didn't help, you might want to make sure you're not mixing compiler versions (e.g. using SFML's Visual Studio 2012 library with your Visual Studio 2013 version).

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the -d suffixes in Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and now everything works as it should.